# What is the opposite of jQuerys "hasClass"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Currently I have some code that reads

```
    if ( $(this).hasClass('.someclass') ) 
     { } 
     else {
     //Do Stuff here.
     }
```

I know this isn't exactly kosher, but it works.

What's the proper way to go about this?  How do I check for the abscence of a class?

Comment: -1: That's a very naïve question - every language has some kind of logical not operator, including javascript.

Comment: Not all of us sprang forth fully formed from the head of Zeus.  Some of us are here to learn.

Comment: Looking back on this two years later, I now completely agree with you,  @rsenna! It's almost embarrassing that this is up here. :/

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Invert the test:

```
if (!$(this).hasClass('someclass'))
```

I think also that the `.` should not be in front of the class name. See the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).